# Flask socketio is too slow

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I have python flask at server end and js on client side. I want to send some logs to client without a request from client. I am trying to implement it with flask socket.io plugin.

Everything looks OK, thanks for below blogs. 
https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-websockets-with-flask-and-gevent

But I can see regular polling going to server and it takes too long to respond. Each polling takes almost 5secs. This delays my other AJAX calls too.
What could be the reason ?

server side-

```
@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/test')
def connect():
    global thread
    with thread_lock:
        if thread is None:
            thread = socketio.start_background_task(target=background_thread)
    socketio.emit('server_msg', 
   {'cause': 'connection', 'status': 'Success', 'count': len(CLIENT.keys())},
                  namespace='/test')


@socketio.on('client_msg', namespace='/test')
def client_msg(msg):
    print(msg)  # TODO: process this msg


def background_thread():
    count = 0
    while True:
        socketio.sleep(5)
        count += 1
        socketio.emit('my_response',
                      {'data': 'Server generated event', 'count': count},
                      namespace='/test')
```

Clinet side -

```
namespace = '/test';
var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + namespace);

socket.on('connect', function () {
    socket.emit('client_msg', {cause: 'connection', details: location});
});
socket.on('server_msg', function (msg) {
    writeLog('log', 'Received ' + msg.cause + ' ' + msg.status)
});
 socket.emit('client_msg', {cause: 'connection', details: location});
```

Network Traffic-

[image]

Comment: There is probably no support for websockets, so the library is downgrading to regular polling method. When you start your app, do you get a warning similar to: `WebSocket transport not available. Install eventlet or gevent and gevent-websocket for improved performance.
` ? 
Can you also print the output of your `pip freeze`

Comment: You should be using WebSocket. The network log that you show indicates that your client is connected using long-polling. Make sure that you install either `eventlet` or `gevent` and `gevent-websocket`, so that the server can offer websocket connections to clients. You also need to review the logic that you use in your event handlers and make sure it does not blog. My guess is that you are doing operations that are blocking, which explains a polling cycle taking 5s.

Comment: Thanks @aqs @Miguel. Everything solved. there were several problems. 1. i was running `app.run` to start app instead of `socketio.run`. 2. cleint websocket.io js cdn was outdated not working with flask socketio. 3. gevent/websocket was not installed. But I still dont understand one thing is when only polling method is used other ajax calls are getting blocked. The thread.lock miguel mentioned is in websocketio.background_tast. not in main thread. But main thread is getting blocked here while polling response is pending.

Comment: You cannot block on anything you do. You are using an async framework, which means that you have only one thread, and your tasks cooperatively pass control to each other. If one of your tasks blocks, then all block. In some cases, monkey patching the Python standard library so that it is async compatible helps solve these problems, so give that a try.

Comment: But delay in ajax calls happens only when gevent is not installed, when polling method is used. after installing gevent ajax calls works as expected with same above code.

Comment: Then what is the problem? The polling method is not efficient, it is only there for clients that do not support websocket.